# Call a method inside a declarative pipeline groovy script

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Basically I have this groovy script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'master'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage("prepare") {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: "SUCCESS", stageResult: "SUCCESS") {
                    step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
                    git url: "git@gitlab.com:tests.git", branch: "master", credentialsId: "test-keys"
                    script {
                        def params = load("test_folder/test.gy")
                        def yml = readYaml file: "test_folder/test.yml"
                        def selectedJobsMap = yml.selected_jobs
                        def extra_parameters = []

                        selectedJobsMap.each { param ->
                            def platformChoices = selectedJobsMap[param.key].collect { it.name as String }
                            params.add (
                                extendedChoice(
                                    name: "${param.key}_PLATFORMS",
                                    description: "Select ${param.key} platforms that you want to run tests",
                                    type: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
                                    multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                                    value: platformChoices.join(',')
                                    )
                                )
                               extra_parameters.add("${param.key}_PLATFORMS")
                        }
                        properties([parameters(params)])
                        def jobsToRun = []

                        extra_parameters.each { platformParam ->
                            def selectedPlatforms = this[platformParam]
                            def exact_platform = "${platformParam}" - "_PLATFORMS"
                            selectedPlatforms.tokenize(',').each { selectedPlatform ->
                                def jobName = selectedJobsMap[exact_platform].find { it.name == selectedPlatform }?.job
                                if (jobName) {
                                    jobsToRun.add(jobName)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        parallel jobsToRun.collectEntries { jobName ->
                            ["Running $jobName": {
                                build_job("$jobName", "${branch_test_code}", "${project_name}")
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                    step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
                } // catchError
            } // steps
        } // stage
    } // stages
}

def build_job(job_name, branch_test_code, project_name) {
    try {
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
            println("Test run started : " + job_name.toString())
            build job: job_name, parameters: [string(name: "branch_test_code", value: branch_test_code),
                                              string(name: "project_name", value: project_name))]
        }
    } catch (err) {
        println("Job exited with an error:")
        println(err.toString())
    } finally {
        try {
            copyArtifacts( filter: "testing/allure-results/*",
                           projectName: job_name,
                           selector: lastCompleted() )
        } catch (err) {
            println("Something went wrong when trying to copy artifacts:")
            println(err.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when I use that build_job there, I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'build_job' found among steps
```

But if I try a more simpler groovy script, it works fine:

```
def build_job(jobName) {
    // Function logic
    echo "Building job: $jobName"
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Call Function') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def myJobName = 'myJob' // Set the job name here
                    build_job(myJobName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix that one? I know that maybe I can declare it inside the Script block but somehow with that method it is not copying the artifacts in the master job. What is different in my complex groovy compared to the simpler one.  Only addition the first one has is the git clone step...

Comment: it works for me. remove everything in prepare stage and execute script { build_job("123","123","123") }.  then add your lines one by one 
if doesnt help update plugins